# What is the point ValidateKeyView in RegistryKey class?

Tags: c#, .net

The [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs) of `RegistryKey` has the following code:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
[ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
[ComVisible(false)]
public static RegistryKey OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, RegistryView view) {
    ValidateKeyView(view);
    CheckUnmanagedCodePermission();
    return GetBaseKey((IntPtr)((int)hKey), view);
}

static private void ValidateKeyView(RegistryView view) 
{
    if (view != RegistryView.Default && view != RegistryView.Registry32 && view != RegistryView.Registry64) 
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_InvalidRegistryViewCheck, ExceptionArgument.view);
}
```

Where `RegistryView` is declared as follows:

```
#if !FEATURE_PAL
namespace Microsoft.Win32 {
    using System;
    
    public enum RegistryView {
        Default      = 0,                           // 0x0000 operate on the default registry view
        Registry64   = Win32Native.KEY_WOW64_64KEY, // 0x0100 operate on the 64-bit registry view
        Registry32   = Win32Native.KEY_WOW64_32KEY, // 0x0200 operate on the 32-bit registry view
    };
}
#endif // !FEATURE_PAL
```

The question is, what's the point of `ValidateKeyView` when *all* of the possible enum values are accepted? Under which circumstances could the check ever fail and throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enums have a base type (`int` if not otherwise specified). An enum can be set to any value from the base type, not just the values which have been assigned names.

So, `(RegistryView)99` would be valid (from a language perspective) as the second argument to `OpenBaseKey`. It would, however, be caught by this check in `ValidateKeyView` and the exception would be thrown.

There is an [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netcore-3.1#System_Enum_IsDefined_System_Type_System_Object_) method which would answer the same question for any enum, but for some reason they've got a specialised version they're using here.

Comment: Ran some tests, seems like `Enum.IsDefined` is about 10x slower than testing for every possible value in an if statement, that's why I imagine they did it here that way. I just wasn't aware that you could assign any arbitrary number you wanted to an enum.

Comment: What is the logic behind allowing any arbitrary number to be cast to any type of enum? Defeats the whole purpose of having an enum to begin with if you can't be guaranteed that the value is within the accepted limits.

Comment: @computeka - Flags enums are the obvious first reason for allowing it - you wouldn't want to have to name every possible combination. After that, it's more pragmatic to allow all values than to try to enforce a "flags only" rule, given how flags are implemented.

Comment: The compiler could still be made to allow that on flags enums and not other enums though, seems like a logical thing to do...